# Url validation in form field

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I added below script to validate url in my form field. It shows valid url.Even if i use magento default class **validate-url** It won't show error.

```
$url=https://www.google.co

if(!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$url))
{
  echo "invalid url";
}
else
{
   echo "valid url";
}
```

How to fix this issue.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what you are trying to achieve here. The url is valid from what I can see so both the validation.js and your regex will return that it is valid. What is the problem that you are looking to solve?

Comment: this is   www.google.co   invalid url. but it shows valid url.Is there any possibilities in the above method.

Answer (score 3):

The regex you have posted does not really do what you think it does. If you post this into a regex tool like:

1. http://www.regexr.com/
2. http://regex101.com/

Then you will be able to debug your regex, but basically what you have is a match for either `http://` or `www.` so in your case `www.google.co` is perfectly valid.

Magento's `js/prototype/validation.js` offers two different url validation options.

1. validate-url - which requires either http:// https:// or ftp://
2. validate-clean-url - which will work without the protocol,

So to make your regex work with the protocol you can use the following:

```
\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/(?:www\.)?)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]
```

But be warned that this will also match `http://a` which I guess you do not want it to do.